# cannot ssh to raspberry pi 400 with ubuntu server 20.10

Tags: networking, server, ssh, raspberrypi, cloud-init

I did a fresh install of ubuntu server 20.10 server 64-bit arm using pi imager in a 16 GB MicroSD card for a raspberry pi 400. I have uncommented the `WLAN0` and subsequent lines, given the Wifi SSID and Password as per the instructions given [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview) the install went fine as I saw in my monitor connected I waited for `cloud-init` to finish but it never gets finished. so I pressed CTRL+D and then tried to connect through ssh using termius on windows 10. but every time it tells that connection timed out. I tried `reboot`, `cloud-init` started again I waited for an hour but nothing happened. I tried googling but didn't get many insights. please help

Comment: Seems like the problem is that cloud-init does not complete. "*connection timed out*" means that either sshd is not running, or that the server is on a different IP address/port than you expect. A more desirable error would be "*invalid password*", which would indicate a running sshd and correct IP address/port.

Comment: I used Hostname -I command to see the ipv4 address used the same address as indicated but no result. Can you please point to a solution to it?

Comment: Oh, so you have local login to the Pi? Your question didn't say so. Test your IP address using `ip a`. Test sshd using `systemctl status sshd.service`. Test connectivity and login on the LAN first. Don't jump into keys and WAN and port forwarding until you have the LAN connectivity figured out.

Comment: yes as I said I have a monitor and a keyboard connected. 'ip a'  gives  WLAN0 as 192.168.43.19. and status as UP and `ssh service` shows as active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cmd to ssh to the machine. terminus is a gives an error. I don't know how it got fixed